# how to retrieve wordpress event manager plugin's event detail using php?

Tags: plugins

I want to retrieve and display event details (Wordpress events manager plugin) using PHP same as we do `the_content(), the_excerpt(), the_title()` for simple posts.
How can I do the same with events manager plugin details like event_start_date, event_ending_date,  event_name, event_time and etc.

Comment: 3rd party plugins are off topic here, please contact use the plugin's support channel(s)

Answer (score 2):

Even this question is off-topic, you can use WordPress dedicated functions to retrieve all event custom fields and display them in your template or use it in your script.

You can have a look to [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to retrieve events post-type and [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) for any custom field. Of course you can also use dedicated function create by the plugin, but it's off-topic.

```
$args = array('post_type'=>'event', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1);
$event_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_start_date', true);
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_end_date', true);
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
// no posts found
}
```

Hope it helps!